# How to link to SDL2 libraries under Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, sdl, static-linking, sdl-2

I have compiled the latest SDL2 libraries, obtained from the 'official' mercurial repository, and followed the instructions for the Ubuntu/Linux build.

But Qt creator fails to link the statically built libraries. Here's the qmake script:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib/libSDL2.a
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

The linker reports several undefined references, including `SDL_Init`.

Comment: is the syntax of this qmake script correct? what improvements could be made to my code?

Answer (score 3):

You have to change your LIBS line to this:

```
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2
```

as `-L` let you define the path where linker looks for libraries to link, while `-l` defines which library to link to. On Unix systems the library called `ASD` is represented by a `libASD.so` file (in this example `.so` is for shared library, in your case there is `.a` as it is static library).

**EDIT**:
I've prepared very simple `main.cpp`:

```
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

int main()
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
  return 0;
}
```

build SDL 2.0.3 as static library with `/usr/local` prefix and I needed to add 2 other libraries to my `.pro` file to compile this. Here it is:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= qt
CONFIG -= app_bundle
SOURCES += main.cpp
LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2 -ldl -lpthread
INCLUDES += /usr/local/include
```

And now it compiles flawlessly.

Comment: we already found this doesn't solve the issue... see the comment to my deleted answer

Comment: thx for hint, but I do not see deleted answers, but tried to investigate it further, so please see my edited answer.

Comment: goob job, I had no time to try by myself :)